# c++ : How to pass a normal c function as hash functor for unordered_map

Tags: c++, function, hash, functor, unordered-map

I've got this hash function is C style:

```
static size_t Wang_Jenkins_hash(size_t h) {
    h += (h << 15) ^ 0xffffcd7d;
    h ^= (h >> 10);
    h += (h << 3);
    h ^= (h >> 6);
    h += (h << 2) + (h << 14);
    return h ^ (h >> 16);
}
```

Then I try to use it for unordered_map's hash parameter. Do I always need to write a c++ functor as a wrapper inorder to use it? Or is there a more convenient ways to pass it as template parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: For performance purposes you really *want* this to be a functor. You can template the `unordered_map` on the `decltype` of the function and use the function pointer, but doing so means the template only specializes to the function prototype, not *that specific function*. If you had two such functions, you'd save an extra copy of the realized template (because they can share the same realization, differing only in which function pointer they call), but it can't optimize beyond that (no inlining, must call through dynamic pointer not baked in address, etc.). Functors are usually faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functors are probably the easiest way to do this.  When you use a free function the syntax becomes

```
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t, decltype(&Wang_Jenkins_hash)>
```

but that is only half of what you need.  Since we are using a function pointer type we need to pass to the map the function to use, and to do that you have to specify how many initial buckets you want along with the function to actually use.  That could be done like

```
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t, decltype(&Wang_Jenkins_hash)> foo(1024, &Wang_Jenkins_hash);
```

If you instead switch to a functor then code can be changed to

```
struct Wang_Jenkins_hash
{
    std::size_t operator()(std::size_t h) noexcept const
    {
        h += (h << 15) ^ 0xffffcd7d;
        h ^= (h >> 10);
        h += (h << 3);
        h ^= (h >> 6);
        h += (h << 2) + (h << 14);
        return h ^ (h >> 16);
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t, Wang_Jenkins_hash> foo;
```

---

If you can use C++20 or newer then you can wrap the fucntion in a lambda to use with the map like

```
auto my_hash = [](auto val) { return Wang_Jenkins_hash(val); };
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t, decltype(my_hash)> foo;
```

Comment: You left off the name `h` in the parameters (and `operator()` should presumably be declared `const`, and maybe `noexcept`, just to reassure the compiler/optimizer; it can probably figure it out on its own, but good to be sure).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks  for pointing that out.  Code updated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

size_t Wang_Jenkins_hash(size_t h) {
    h += (h << 15) ^ 0xffffcd7d;
    h ^= (h >> 10);
    h += (h << 3);
    h ^= (h >> 6);
    h += (h << 2) + (h << 14);
    return h ^ (h >> 16);
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t, decltype(&Wang_Jenkins_hash)> m(0, &Wang_Jenkins_hash); 
    return 0;
}
```